# Simple python query

Tags: python

So my problem is that i have a down-loader that has the percent of the file downloaded so far.
And sometimes the percent doesent go up by one or some times it goes up by 4 or 5 etc.
so say my files percent of download went like this:

```
0 % done
1 % done
2 % done
2 % done
2 % done
3 % done
3 % done
3 % done
3 % done
3 % done
4 % done
5 % done
6 % done
7 % done
7 % done
8 % done
9 % done
10 % done
10 % done
11 % done
12 % done
12 % done
12 % done
13 % done
14 % done
14 % done
15 % done
16 % done
17 % done
17 % done
17 % done
17 % done
17 % done
18 % done
19 % done
20 % done
20 % done
20 % done
20 % done
21 % done
22 % done
23 % done
24 % done
25 % done
26 % done
26 % done
27 % done
28 % done
28 % done
29 % done
30 % done
30 % done
31 % done
32 % done
33 % done
33 % done
33 % done
33 % done
33 % done
34 % done
35 % done
36 % done
36 % done
37 % done
37 % done
38 % done
38 % done
38 % done
39 % done
40 % done
40 % done
40 % done
41 % done
41 % done
41 % done
42 % done
42 % done
43 % done
43 % done
44 % done
44 % done
45 % done
45 % done
46 % done
46 % done
47 % done
47 % done
47 % done
47 % done
47 % done
48 % done
48 % done
49 % done
50 % done
50 % done
50 % done
51 % done
51 % done
51 % done
52 % done
52 % done
53 % done
54 % done
54 % done
54 % done
54 % done
54 % done
54 % done
54 % done
54 % done
55 % done
55 % done
55 % done
55 % done
56 % done
56 % done
56 % done
56 % done
56 % done
56 % done
57 % done
58 % done
59 % done
60 % done
60 % done
61 % done
61 % done
62 % done
62 % done
63 % done
64 % done
65 % done
65 % done
66 % done
66 % done
67 % done
67 % done
67 % done
68 % done
68 % done
69 % done
69 % done
70 % done
70 % done
71 % done
72 % done
73 % done
74 % done
74 % done
75 % done
76 % done
77 % done
78 % done
79 % done
79 % done
80 % done
80 % done
81 % done
81 % done
81 % done
82 % done
83 % done
84 % done
85 % done
85 % done
85 % done
85 % done
86 % done
87 % done
87 % done
87 % done
87 % done
87 % done
87 % done
88 % done
89 % done
89 % done
89 % done
90 % done
90 % done
90 % done
91 % done
91 % done
92 % done
93 % done
94 % done
94 % done
95 % done
95 % done
96 % done
97 % done
98 % done
99 % done
99 % done
99 % done
100 % done
```

i would want the number that the percent went up... so if it was:

```
0 % done
1 % done
2 % done
2 % done
2 % done
3 % done
3 % done
3 % done
3 % done
3 % done
4 % done
5 % done
```

the result would be some thing like:

```
1
1
0
0
0
1
0
0
0
0
1
1
1
```

i know this is very simple so far ive tried some thing like:

```
import random

a=0
z=0
c=0
while a!=100:
    b=random.randint(1,2)
    z+=a
    if b==1:

        a+=1
    z-=a
    print a
    c+=a
    final=c-a
    print final
```

im almost positive that im making this more complicated then it has to be.

Comment: Step one: use nicer variable names. `a`, `b`, `c` and `z` are *not* good variable names. That makes it a lot more complicated than it has to be. Step two: follow [PEP 8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) and make `a=0` `a = 0`, `a!=100` `a != 100`, etc.; this will also make your code much more readable.

Comment: The variable `z` is currently serving no purpose whatsoever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given `x` is the list of percents (of completion for your download):

```
x = [ 0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3 ]
```

Then use "finite differencing" to get the change:

```
delta_x = [ x[i+1] - x[i] for i in xrange(0, len(x)-1) ]
```

I've written it as a list comprehension, but you could also do it with a loop.

Comment: If you get these values "on the fly", you would simply print `current - previous` and then set `previous = current`.

Answer (score 0):

My version:

```
>>> s = """
... 1
... 2
... 3
... 3
... 3
... 4
... 4
... 5
... 6
... 7
... 7
... 7
... 7
... 8
... """
>>> percents = map(int, filter(bool, s.splitlines()))
>>> percents
[1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8]
>>> map(lambda (a, b): b - a, zip(percents[:-1], percents[1:]))
[1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1]
>>>
```

Comment: Use list comprehensions. Map + Filter burn my eyes

Comment: Oh, sorry about your eyes, didn't mean do to no harm, fella. I'd recommend you wearing some kind of code-goggles before reading functional code, though.

Comment: @dmedvinsky: the point is that you should use Python style for anything when working in Python. And why not just do `.split()` instead of making more work for yourself by using `splitlines()`? `percents = [int(n) for n in s.split()]`, `[b - a for a, b in zip(percents[:-1], percents[1:]]`

Answer (score 0):

I would write it using the [`itertools`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html) module. The major difference from list comprehensions and other approaches in the other answers is that we do not need to calculate the positions of the elements we should iterate to (no need to use slices). All this logic is covered with the iterators which will just raise `StopIteration` when needed.

```
from itertools import tee, izip

current_iter, previous_iter = tee(iter(L))
next(current_iter,None)

for current,previous in izip(current_iter, previous_iter):
    print current-previous
```

`iter(L)` creates an iterator of `list L`.

[`tee`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.tee) creates 2 iterators of `iter(L)` which return the same values.

`next(current_iter,None)` advances the `current_iter` by 1 position. Also, if the `L` has 1 or 0 values, no exception will be raised and `None` will be returned (to achieve such a behavior we use `None` as the second argument of the `next` function. It's not a problem that we make the code swallow the `Stop iteration` exception since it will be raised again in the next usage if this iterator (and actually will be caught by `for` loop which will just stop iterating).

[`izip`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip) is used to advance through the iterators `current_iter` and `previous_iter` simultaneously.

That's it. Not very complicated.

It's also possible to make a generator of it:

```
from itertools import tee, izip

def Gen(L):
    current_iter, previous_iter = tee(iter(L))
    next(current_iter,None)

    for current,previous in izip(current_iter, previous_iter):
        yield current-previous
```

And then, the generator can be used:

```
it1 = Gen(L)
for value in it1:
    print value
```